# MasterPage button fires after content page postback

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

Not sure if this is the prescribed order of events, but I have a logout button on my masterpage, whose event doesn't fire until after the content page's page_load fires.

On some pages there is some time-consuming code in page_load, and this makes the logout process take way too long.

The catch-22 is that in the content's Page_Load, I can't check any property I might set in the Master's logout_click event, because it hasn't fired yet.

How can I make the MasterPage's logout button fire first and go directly to the redirect which I have in the click event?
Thanks very much,
JimO.

Comment: Actually its is simple page life cycle process. Page_Load always gets called prior to mater page's load thus the behavior is same as resulted.

Comment: This is default behavior.

Comment: Kundan, thanks, I guess that answers it.  How do I give a + or mark your comment as answer?

Comment: @jimo3, you can upvote and/or accept any of the answers below. Please go through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/about) tour to know more about [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 3):

What you are facing is the default behavior due to page life cycle.

But you can try the following steps to work around your problem

1. Instead of having a `Button`/`LinkButton` and writing code for `LogOut` on master page in `Click` event, you can have a `HyperLink`.
2. Set its `NavigationURL` to point to a logout page which will handle only the code for `LogOut`.
3. Write the `LogOut` code in the `Page_Load` event of that page.

Answer (score 0):

Most people put something like the following in their page_load

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack()) {
  // do stuff to initialize everything
}
```

This way when a postback occurs you don't necessarily have to reload a bunch of stuff.

Comment: Yes, I have that block in page_load, but there is something there done on postbacks.  It has to do with a DevExpress control (I did not build this page).  It sets the datasource for the Devexpress grid.  If I remove it, then the filtering part of the grid stops working. I would think the grid is saved in viewstate but I'm not very familiar with DX controls.

Comment: @jimo3: In that case, do what Devraj said and just turn it into a link that goes to a page that actually logs them out.